# Pycaret installation issue?

Tags: pycaret

I'm trying to install pycaret and used all the possible solutions. But still give me the following error

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
  Failed to build numpy
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

what would be a solution?